# XDMP-FORESTERR Permission Denied

Tags: marklogic

When I try to create a Forest on a new location I get this error:

```
2016-09-09 21:37:42.645 Alert: XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in initialization of forest mlepub-spinning: SVC-FILSTAT: File status error: stat64 '/media/thijs/Forests/mlepubdata/Forests/mlepub': Permission denied
```

What should the configuration be? Even `chmod 777` does not do the trick. I have used this many times before and never with any problem, maybe an issue in `8.0-4.2`?

[[EDIT]]

**Parent directory**
The mount point is owned by root, the folder on this level is owned by `thijs` and the mlepub directory is owned by `daemon`. Also, I've removed any restriction from the folder using `chmod 777` and have also tested this without those crazy permissions.

```
[11:06] /media/thijs/Forests

total 28
drwx------  4 thijs  thijs   4096 Sep 12 10:52 .
drwxr-x---+ 3 root   root    4096 Sep 12 10:52 ..
drwx------  2 root   root   16384 Nov 12  2015 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx  2 daemon daemon  4096 Sep 12 10:52 mlepub
```

**The data directory**
Shows every possible permission and ownership to `daemon` and that the parent directory is owned by `thijs`.

```
thijs@Puc
[11:06] /media/thijs/Forests/mlepub

total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 daemon daemon 4096 Sep 12 10:52 .
drwx------ 4 thijs  thijs  4096 Sep 12 10:52 ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...the user needs to have read and execute rights from the root until the
>   defined location and only write rights on the final location...

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory

Answer (score 3):

By default, MarkLogic runs as the user `daemon`. Make sure that the directory (and it's containing directories) have read and execute permissions. You cannot list the contents of a directory without execute.

Verify that `daemon` (or whichever user MarkLogic is configured to run as) has execute permissions on each directory in the path. It may be that the permissions on the containing folder(s) need to be adjusted as well.

Comment: on each directory in the path? do you mean up the tree, like surrendering an entire drive to ML just so it can write a few files somewhere in a subdirectory?

Comment: First verify whether permissions are the issue. You might switch to the daemon user and try to cd into that directory and use ls. If that is the issue, you could add the daemon user to a group that has sufficient rights. However you choose to enable, the process has to be able to get to and modify the contents of that dir.

Comment: One does not simply switch to user `daemon`. Also, I edited my question with some directory information, every and all users can write to the location.

Comment: The Forests directory itself is not writable for daemon. MarkLogic must be able to create forest directories there. If you have sudo privilege, you can switch to daemon user with `sudo su daemon`..

Comment: Additionally: consider doing `(sudo) chown (-R) daemon:daemon /media/thijs/Forests`..

Comment: ah yes, my bad on the copy/pasting.. the permission error is on the `mlepub` level and not on the `Forests` level, corrected my question

Comment: all permissions are given, I will not sacrifice an entire disk for MarkLogic so I will not set all permission up the tree te make the Forest work, this seems to be the problem, all levels ABOVE the Forests must have the same permissions.